# Read mails from a mail box in SharePoint 2010

Tags: list, email, attachments, incoming-email

- Let's say I have a mail address , **jithu@abc.com** .
- I will get mails from different mail Id's.
- All mails have an excel sheet attached.
- Excel sheet has two fields, 1) another email Id 2) A name

Now my questions are,

1) can I store this mails into a list or directory from my mail box. Can I store the attachment to a different field in the list/ or to a different directory.

2) After getting the mail can I read the fields email id and the name from the excel sheet?

3) Can I forward or send another mail to the mail Id in the excelsheet.

Since these questions are related I put it together. Please give some guidence..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to mail-enable to the list so that it was able to receive email.  You will then make sure that AD is able to recognize that list's email address as a valid mail recipient.  Then add that email address as a recipient of jithu@abc.com.

I am not sure about handling the attachment though.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx

Comment: I have configured the email setting using drop folder method. Now how could I enable a list to accept an email. Or to which mail Id I should send the mail, from my mail ID.

Comment: Got it worked in lists !!

Comment: Did the Drop folder method work with the attachment?